# Need help with contradictory statement

Tags: speech

How would these 2 quotes be considered as contradictory?

"The worst hell you will ever face is the hell you create with your own mind."

"I’m very capable of changing to anything I want to change to."

Comment: They are not exactly 180 degrees apart, but they could be considered contradictory.  Of course, they are both philosophical and metaphorical, so that they can still be "true" (to a degree) yet contradict each other.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question as off-topic because it asks for comprehension, the analysis and contrasting of two statements themselves open to various interpretations, rather than enquiring about the meaning of a particular word or phrase, or construction. Philosophy.SE?

Comment: Changing to? Like to what sort of a what?

Comment: It's unclear -- what is your question.  They obviously contradict each other, but that's not unusual (just watch the news).

Comment: I don't see them as contradictory at all.  You make your own hell if you refuse to try to change yourself.

Answer (score 1):

The first one says that one's mind cannot be truly changed and that is the cause of a bad situation.

The second is a poor way of saying *I’m capable of changing myself, or my mind, to whatever I want or in any way that I choose.*

They make contradictory claims about the self or the mind. The first does so generally while the second takes it personally. Some more detail about where these appear and why they need to be compared would be helpful in keeping this question open.